# Is it possible access RealmSwift DB of application from its Share Extension?

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to develop an application that saves "Bus" object in Realm and each bus has its name, plateNm, and etc. I am using RealmSwift now.

My question is:

> Is it possible to access the data of application in share extension?

I want users can exchange their Bus Object. I figured out that I can change my realm data to json and json to realm.

But, How can I access the DB of application?

I think import and export Realm data as json is possible. How can I update my DB when I get the json file?

I searched about it and saw several suggestions that using shared container between App group.

Could you let me know how to save realm data in shared container? or is there any other way to access DB in Share Extension?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to put the realm DB access code in a shared framework that you could access from the extension, don't forget to declare you container like this

`let container =   NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.com.a.b")`

but you should sync your DB from the extension, this is a known bug: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4490